Prove $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq 0$ if $f(x)$ is convex without twice differentiability.
I've recently been trying to understand some proofs about convex functions. The definition of convex I'm using is:

Let $f(x)$ be a once differentiable function defined on $[a, b]$. $f$ is convex iff we
have that $f'$ is increasing. (Not necessarily strictly increasing).

So with this definition, I want to prove the result $$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq 0 $$
for $a \leq x \leq b$. The way I was able to "do" it was falsely assuming the function was also twice differentiable and making sign arguments related to $f''\geq 0$. Is there any way to prove the above fact without resorting to this false assumption? Also, please don't reference "the graph always being above the tangent" or "the graph being always below the secant line" since I encountered this problem while trying to show that these definitions of convexity are equivalent. Thank you.
For completeness, here is the argument I used:
Differentiating, we get $$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \frac{f'(x)(x-a)-(f(x)-f(a))}{(x-a)^2} $$
The denominator is already positive, so we need to prove that $$f'(x)(x-a)-(f(x)-f(a))\geq0$$
At $x=a$ the LHS vanishes. I will now show that the LHS is increasing, so that it will be always greater than or equal to 0.
Differentiating LHS,
$$f''(x)(x-a)+f'(x)-f'(x)$$
$$=f''(x)(x-a)$$
Which is positive through the false assumption that $f''(x) \geq 0$. This proves $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \frac{f'(x)(x-a)-(f(x)-f(a))}{(x-a)^2} $ is nonnegative and hence the original claim is proved. How may we prove this without twice differentiability?(and without using the "geometric" definitions of convexity i.e. tangent line always below, secant line always above etc.)

By the mean value theorem, there is some $c \in (a, x)$ with $f'(c) = \dfrac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$. Then
$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \frac{f'(x)(x-a) - (f(x)-f(a))}{(x-a)^2} = \frac{f'(x) - f'(c)}{x - a} \ge 0$$
because $f'(x) \ge f'(c)$.

I don't think you're proving what you were asked. You said that you were asked to show that $f'(x)$ is increasing but instead showed that $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ is, and $f'(x)$ and the other expression need only agree at $x=a$, while they could be different anywhere else.
I assume that your definition of convexity is that $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)\le \lambda f(x)+ (1-\lambda)f(y)$ for $\lambda\in[0,1]$. What you can do is use this definition of convexity to show that if $r, s, t\in[a,b]$ are such that $r< s< t$, then
$$\frac{f(s)-f(r)}{s-r}\le\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s}$$
This inequality means that the slope from the point $(r,f(r))$ to the point $(s,f(s))$ is less than the slope from the point $(s,f(s))$ to the point $(t,f(t))$. In other words, $f$ has a higher average increase in $(s,t)$ than in $(r,s)$, which should make intuitive sense for convex functions. With this inequaligy you can show that that $f'$ is increasing.

Hello, I've edited the question to reflect my question better. The definition for convexity I'm using is that $f'(x)$ is increasing, which is in the quote block in the original post. With this definition, I indeed want to prove that $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ is increasing too.
